# create an object difference between var x = new and datatype x = new datatype

Tags: c#, object

what is the difference between the following syntax

```
      1.  var dtm = new DataTableManager();
      2.  DataTableManager dtm1 = new DataTableManager();
```

Many thanks,

Comment: There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference if used within a method. You cannot use var as a class scoped variable through. Also var can be used to handle anonymous types, which is not possible otherwise.

For more information check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx